# django timeuntil ignoring timezone

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I am testing django 1.4 features. for me the most important is the TZ control.

I am using PG and the DateTimeField is working perfect saving the datetime having in count `settings.TIME_ZONE` also Im setting other differents timezones with `pytz` and looks good.

but the problem is with [timesince tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince), is ignoring the TZ:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.timesince import timeuntil

class Foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()

def remaining(self):
    res = timeuntil(self.date, datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.get_current_timezone()))
    return res
```

`foo.remaining()` is always returning the remaining count with the default timezone.

thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, tested rendering it on a template with other timezones.